# I am learning D3.js but I don't get the same console output as tutorials

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning D3.js through tutorials, but I am not seeing the same output on my developer console in Google Chrome. For example, I want to bind an array of three integers: 1,2,3. I am using v4.1.1

According to the tutorial, I should be able to easily access my data:

[image]

But this is what I get and can't access the data so easily. I am lost and would greatly appreciate the community's feedback.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There two potential problems.

1. You might be using d3.v4 and your tutorial might be using d3.v3
2. It looks like your code is slightly different from the tutorials. In the tutorial you posted the data is a nested array `[[1,2,3]]` but in your screenshot there is only one dimensional array `[1,2,3]` (one level of brackets).

Comment: Thank you! I figured out where to find the nested array!